Agora video call With DeepAR
How can I implement a agora video call with DeepAR in React Native?
Can anyone help on how to implement a agora video calling functionality with deepAR effect in React native specific.
I was implementing separately react-native-agora and react-native-deepar functionality but I did not have any idea about how to both combine implementations in react native.
Separatly both package working fine but i need to video calling with deepAR functionality in one frame.
